# Rich text editor change style

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor

I have installed ckeditor (Rich text editor) for my blog. Of course I installed it to customize my posts more than the default textarea.

But I have a small problem. On my homepage I preview the first words of the post as a small description. Underneath their is a "read more" button. The problem is that you can see the whole decoration in the preview. But I just want a default white text.

[image]

In the first posts I used no decoration. Just typing some text like I would do in a normal editor. As you can see it show fine. But there is one problem: The CKEditor uses a custom class and I don't know how to change the color to white. Thats the first problem.

The second problem is as you can see the all the decoration in the second preview. What I want is that something removes all the decoration and just shows all the text.

I know this is a really large question but I hope someone knows how to fix it.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: A jsfiddle / codepen to reproduce the issue would help a lot...

Comment: I'm guessing they not only add custom classes, but custom DOM elements as part of that string (IE, the string isn't `Kijk dit is een post...`, its `<b>Kijk dit is een post</b>...`), meaning you would have to strip out those DOM elements, or save a seperate preview string that doesn't have those injected in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

string strip_tags ( string $str [, string $allowable_tags ] )